# Suggestions for writing a web client for an existing client/server application

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, sockets, web

Basically, the existing application consists of a C# server application running as a windows service and using sockets to communicate along with client applications that connect to this server.

The server essentially controls several camera systems: user can log in and move camera around, take video, and take photos.

The primary concern is latency and user state memory without too much overhead.

Basically the model is like this:

Camera <---> Server <---> Clients

I want:

Camera <---> Server <---> Clients including web client

Now, for the web side, I guess the two fundamental approaches are:

a) Web client acts directly as a socket client connecting to the server directly. This would minimize latency. Is this possible using HTML5/JavaScript without resorting to something like flash?

b) Web client communicates to web server using something like web sockets or polling with AJAX. Web server communicates with application server. Now complications arise with persisting the server/server communication and handling user credentials and such. Also, some latency is introduced. The up-side is the client will work behind firewalls/etc. as long as the client can access the web site.

Basically, I've been doing a lot of inconclusive research, so at this point I am looking for experienced input... Where would you recommend I start? What technologies would I be smart to investigate? What will allow for the most rapid development/learning with reasonable performance?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate SO question. You need to be more specific than giving a list of requirements and asking basically "Okay, what do I do now?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you take the different route:

Camera <----> (Existing, C#) Server <----> (New webapp in) Webserver <----> Client

and do the translation stuff in the server-sided app.

- This has a huge impact on the security surface of your application, as the camera server itself is no longer exposed to (untrusted) web clients, but only to the (trusted) web app.
- It makes life much easier: The translation between a simple and well understood JSON over AJAX request inside a server-sided app is trivial (and browser independant)